# "Cannot set property 'value' of null" when selecting an option of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I'm making a dropdown menu, everything seems to be working fine, but when I select an option y gives me this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Here is the HTML code of the dropdown:

```
<div id="dropdown">
           <label for="tipo_envio">Seleccione el tipo de envío: </label>
           <select name="tipo_envio" id="tipo_envio" onchange="hideElement()">
               <option value="aereo">Aereo</option>
               <option value="maritimo">Maritimo</option>
           </select>
 </div>
```

And the function in JS:

```
function hideElement() {
           if (document.getElementById("#tipo_envio").value = "aereo") {
               document.getElementById("#calculo_maritimo").style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById("#calculo_aereo").style.display = "block";
           } else {
               document.getElementById("#calculo_aereo").style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById("#calculo_maritimo").style.display = "block";
           }
       };
```

I want to make it so that when I select one option of the list, one part of the page hides and the other appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use `==` or `===` when cmoparing values. You have a single `=` in your `if` statement. That will never work like you want it to.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed! Indeed the error was that I put "=" instead of "==" or "===", this is the first program that I've made in JavaScript and my only previous knowledge in JS was simply making a variable, so it has been pretty hard but I've learned a lot, so thanks to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `getElementById`, you don't need to use the `#` character. It is necessary for selectors (for the method `querySelector` for example)

Also, as @I-wrestled-a-bear-once said, you need to use `==` or `===` when checking for equality.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to js so I didn't know about == and ===

Answer (score 1):

If you use `getElementById` don't use "#" in string:

```
function hideElement() {
  const select = document.getElementById("tipo_envio");
  
  if (select.value== "aereo") {
    document.getElementById("calculo_maritimo").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("calculo_aereo").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("calculo_aereo").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("calculo_maritimo").style.display = "block";
  }
};
```

Comment: `value.value` will be undefined, because `value` already contains the value. also, there is no reason to mess with the selected index at all. `value = select.value` will work just fine.

Comment: I fixed all bugs, thanks for comment :). I pasted code from wrong pen

Answer (score 0):

Never use `#` for `getElementById()`. Also, `if(x = y)` means set the value of x to y then evaluate its truthiness.
You're looking for the `===` comparison operator instead

```
document.getElementById("tipo_envio").value === "aereo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. The error comes from this row:

`if (document.getElementById("#tipo_envio").value = "aereo") {`

First of all, when using `getElementById(...)` the `#` is implied, so you should not include it.

Second, you're using `=`, which means you try assigning the value `"aereo"` to the drop-down. You should use `==` or `===` for comparison.